# Is there any solution to create video stream from image/images?

Tags: encoding, video-streaming, streaming, video-processing, rtmp

I would like to generate video content from text/images with provided content size. Have tried many options from FFmpeg to h264 encoders. So a want to build a solution that takes one image or array of images and generate video stream, let's say rtmp. Also image is always changing, adding text, change color etc. I have tried with Golang.

Comment: If you are asking for tools, I think you are in the wrong site. Other sites may know better. If you are asking how to program it, you should provide more data (what you really want, what are your problems, and what you already programmed). Note: you just describe "streaming" (source doesn't matter: webcam, video import, screen duplication, images from web/programs, ...)

Comment: As I said I want to create image from data, then convert it into video that is streamed. I’m not asking for tools, I am looking for solution or at lest how this can be done.